# uTorrent and PuTTY -> How to turn the connection into an active one?

Tags: windows-7, putty, port-forwarding, tunnel, ssh-tunnel

There is an active, and passive mode when we talk about torrent. Passive, is when you can't connect to the peers actively. Active is when your ports are forwarder, and others can connect to you.

What I did so far, is installed a Debian on my server. Then I added `GatewayPorts yes` into my sshd_config file. After that, in PuTTY, I set up the following configuration:
- Remote ports do the same
- Local ports accept connections from other hosts
Then I added a new forward like:
`4D8080` (IPv4, Dynamic, at my PC's port 8080).

After this, I set my uTorrent to use SOCKS5 proxy for *every* possible connection, at `localhost`, port `8080`. But, my client will show the red sign at the bottom-right part.

Is there  a solution to this? (Something is surely not right, I get 0 DHT nodes too.)

Comment: Your description tells us how you connect to your debian server, so presumably your outgoing torrent connection is putty->debian->internet.  You are advertising a port range in your client, how are these ports getting to the debian server?  Is it on a public IP?

Comment: The server is on a public IP, yes. I'm using a random port (let's say 23456 in my torrent client), and a 8085 like port in my PuTTY + uTorrent's proxy page. My PC (uTorrent) -> SOCKS5 (127.0.0.1) -> PuTTY (remote IP) -> Debian server (with public IP and SSH server, and `GatewayPorts yes`) -> Internet.

Comment: There is a howto by the MyEnTunnel's author, which sadly doesn't work. http://nemesis2.qx.net/forums/index.php?topic=23.0 But maybe, someone will be able to solve the mystery.

Answer (score 4):

Your two problems (not being connectable and not finding DHT nodes) are related, but they have different causes and different (partial) solutions.

### Connectivity

To be able to accept incoming connections, you have to accomplish three things:

- Forward the remote port uTorrent listens to to your client machine.

  In **Preferences → Connection → Listening Port → Port used for incoming connections**, uTorrent lets you specify a single port for incoming connections. Set it to `40000` (for example).

  To forward this port, enter **Connection → SSH → Tunnels** in PuTTY and add the following forwarded port:

  ```
  R40000 127.0.0.1:40000
  ```

  Checking **Local ports accept connections from other hosts** is neither required nor desired for this. It's used to allow other machines to connect to your computer and make use of the forwarded local and dynamic ports.

  Checking **Remote ports do the same** is only required if you set `GatewayPorts` to `clientspecified`  on your server. If it is set to `yes` or `no`, this option has no effect.
- Make uTorrent report the correct IP to the tracker.

  By default, the tracker results to its best guess when adding an IP to the peer list.    The dynamic port forwarding *might* (this depends on the tracker) cause a local IP address (`10.xxx.yyy.zzz`) to get added to the peer list. The IP that should get added instead is the one of your *server*.

  You can specify it in **Preferences → BitTorrent → IP/Hostname to report to tracker**. Not all trackers respect this setting, but it should help.
- Allow uTorrent to accept incoming connections.

  In **Preferences → Advanced**, you can modify the bit field [bt.transp_disposition](http://www.tmsnetwork.org/blog/%C2%B5torrent-utorrent-bt-transp_disposition-values-explained/).

  When using a SSH tunnel with remote port forwarding for TCP and UDP connections (see below), I'd set it to `13`. This allows outgoing TCP and incoming TCP and UDP peer-to-peer connections.

### DHT / UDP connections

PuTTY and SSH don't listen on any UDP port, so neither the dynamic nor the remote port you forwarded will work out of the box. Since DHT uses UDP, it won't work either.

- #### Incoming UDP connections

  If you install [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/) on you server (`apt-get install socat`) and on your client machine (using [Socat for Windows](http://blog.gentilkiwi.com/programmes/socat#englishversion)), you can transform incoming UDP connections to TCP connections, forward them through the tunnel and convert them back to UDP connections on your client machine.

  To do so, execute

  ```
  socat udp4-listen:40000,reuseaddr,fork tcp:localhost:50000
  ```

  on your server and

  ```
  socat tcp4-listen:50000,reuseaddr,fork UDP:localhost:40000
  ```

  on your client machine.

  The choice of port number `50000` is arbitrary, but it has to be different from `40000` (to be able to distinguish one connection type from the other).

  For the actual forwarding, enter **Connection → SSH → Tunnels** in PuTTY and add the following forwarded port:

  ```
  R50000 127.0.0.1:50000
  ```
- #### Outgoing UDP connections

  Routing outgoing UDP connections through the SSH tunnel isn't as easy and might even be impossible. The method from above won't work since `socat` only listens to a specific port, while the destination port of an outgoing connection could be anything. Also, once a TCP packet reaches the dynamically forwarded port, you can't control what happens to it.

  It would be possible to set up UDP connections on a peer-by-peer basis, but that's probably not worth the effort. DHT should work fine with incoming connections, once you've conected to the first peer.

Comment: Another five-star answer Dennis. I'll try this out tomorrow. :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to do it the other way around ... 
You need to have remote ports accepting connections from other hosts. And a firewall rule on your server allowing incoming traffic to the listening port set in utorrent preferences. (although i'm not sure if this gets propagated through socks - you need to try it out and check `netstat`)

Comment: As far as I know, GatewayPorts do the first thing you mentioned. About the firewall... there is no firewall, no iptables. It's disabled.

Comment: (Uhm.. and if someone knows what I'm missing, please elaborate. Be noob friendly, I'm new to this thing. And I guess if someone will do a Google search on the topic, will appreciate it too. :))

Answer (score 0):

The dynamic SOCKS proxy mode (the "D" option) cannot handle incoming connections for you because there's no such provision in the protocol. A proxy protocol is only supposed to handle your outgoing connections after all.

You need to add a remote redirection (the "R" option), so your SSH server listens on a port and redirects the packets to you. See the following man page extract:

```
 -R [bind_address:]port:host:hostport
     Specifies that the given port on the remote (server) host is to
     be forwarded to the given host and port on the local side.  This
     works by allocating a socket to listen to port on the remote
     side, and whenever a connection is made to this port, the connec-
     tion is forwarded over the secure channel, and a connection is
     made to host port hostport from the local machine.

     Port forwardings can also be specified in the configuration file.
     Privileged ports can be forwarded only when logging in as root on
     the remote machine.  IPv6 addresses can be specified by enclosing
     the address in square braces or using an alternative syntax:
     [bind_address/]host/port/hostport.

     By default, the listening socket on the server will be bound to
     the loopback interface only.  This may be overriden by specifying
     a bind_address.  An empty bind_address, or the address '*', indi-
     cates that the remote socket should listen on all interfaces.
     Specifying a remote bind_address will only succeed if the
     server's GatewayPorts option is enabled (see sshd_config(5)).
```

Note however this port forwarding feature can change origin IP of the remote peer which can mess up the bittorrent protocol. If this is the case, you need to use VPN instead of SSH.

Comment: Where can I find this "R" option in PuTTY? Or should I use Cygwin? By the way, I tried using the remote redirection (in Tunnelier), but uTorrent didn't work at all.

Comment: (The protocol stuff: BTguard.com uses SOCKS5 proxy too and it works perfectly. That's why I thought PuTTY/SSH would work.)

Comment: The option is called "Remote" in the same place you find the "Dynamic" option.

Comment: SOCKS5 does support UDP which is usually used to do NAT-traversal. However, SSH may not support this.

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong. I tick the "Remote" option. THEN, Source port: 8081 (port is forwarded in my router, just in case); Destination: 80.211.203.92:23456 and IPv4. But after launching the connection, set uTorrent to this address, and it can't connect at all. :/

Comment: The source port is the one that your SSH server will listen to and the destination is where the packets will be forwarded on your SSH client. If your Bittorrent is listening on port 12345 you should set: source 12345 destination: localhost:12345.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1991/discussion-between-shiki-and-billc-cn)

Comment: No success.  It just can't connect. Port forwarded, set it just as you said.

Comment: I can only pass the port forwarding test in uTorrent, but it seems the source IP is re-written which causes problem with the protocol...

Comment: This makes me think about BTGuard again. How did they solve this? I mean. Their service is a SOCKS5 proxy. WITH AES256. How? :|